# kill user who is idle for more than 3 hours

Tags: debian, ssh, sftp, sshd

I have a user who logs in via `sftp` but he opens a lot of sessions and keep them opened. This will make `ssh` and `sftp` very slow for all other users. I thought about using

```
ClientAliveInterval   number in seconds
ClientAliveCountMax number of counts
```

but it will affect all users and it can tricked by adding other parameters from client machine(s).

Note I am using `Debian 8.3` and I am enabling server `ftp` service too.

My questions:

1. Is there a way to drop the user session if there is no real action
   like copy, move ..etc
2. Can I add parameters above for just one user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ssh daemon does not know what actions a user does.  If you want to check that, you would have to either turn on detailed auditing (slow) or accounting, and analyze the logs (in either case, fairly slow).

Further reading:

- [How to Monitor User Activity with psacct or acct Tools](http://www.tecmint.com/how-to-monitor-user-activity-with-psacct-or-acct-tools/)
- [How to keep a detailed audit trail of what’s being done on your Linux systems](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-log-user-activity-using-process-accounting.html)
- [Process Accounting HOW-TO](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/text/Process-Accounting)

Comment: thanks for the info, one more question if you dont mind is there a command similar to `who` can list `sftp` users? not one of `ps` commands, I guess I found a way to it but my problem now is `who` only showing ssh users only not alone with `sftp`.

Comment: no - but you can pick the information out of `ps`, since each sftp session uses `/usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server`.